# Consulta SQL Oracle com Group By começando e terminando em dias diferentes

Tags: oracle, select, data

Eu preciso somar registros númericos agrupados por dia dentro de um mês, eu tenho o timestamp de todos os registros, mas não consigo fazer um group by pois o meu dia começa com registro das 00:15 e termina com o registro da 00:00 do dia seguinte, então não posso agrupar com **TO_CHAR(trunc(date), 'dd/MM/YYYY')** já que o primeiro registro do dia, no caso 00:00, eu não considero para o dia atual e o último que é 00:00, que eu preciso considerar, pertence ao dia seguinte, resumindo, um exemplo de um dia é 01/05/2020 00:15 até 02/05/2020 00:00 (somo todos os registros desse período e componho um dia).

O meu SELECT atual está assim:

```
SELECT
    period,
    liquid    
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ( nvl(SUM(m.coluna1), 0) - nvl(SUM(m.coluna2), 0) ) liquid,            
            TO_CHAR(trunc(m.date), 'dd/MM/YYYY') period
        FROM
            tabela m
        WHERE
            m.id_registro IN (id_registro)
            AND m.date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/05/2020 00:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('01/06/2020 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        GROUP BY
            TO_CHAR(trunc(m.date), 'dd/MM/YYYY')
    ) vrdm
```

Como eu monto esse select para considerar um dia começando sempre 00:15 e terminando 00:00 do dia seguinte e agrupar isso por dia para somar os registros?

Eu preciso que fique assim:

```
  period   |  liquid
01/05/2020 |   3000   -> SOMA(todas diferenças entre coluna1 e coluna2 entre 01/05 00:15 e 02/05 00:00)
02/05/2020 |   4000   -> SOMA(todas diferenças entre coluna1 e coluna2 entre 02/05 00:15 e 03/05 00:00)
03/05/2020 |   3500   -> SOMA(todas diferenças entre coluna1 e coluna2 entre 03/05 00:15 e 04/05 00:00)
```

A tabela que eu tenho é assim:

```
       date       |   coluna1   |  coluna2
01/05/2020 00:00  |     50      |     20
01/05/2020 00:15  |     60      |     30
01/05/2020 00:30  |     70      |     40
       ...        |             |
01/05/2020 23:45  |     80      |     50
02/05/2020 00:00  |     100     |     40
02/05/2020 00:15  |     110     |     35
```

Comment: Não tenho o banco aqui para testar, mas retirar 15 minutos de m.date com - NUMTODSINTERVAL(15, 'MINUTE') não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: @LeandroLuque onde eu usaria? Você poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: No GROUP BY. Mantenha a sua instrução igual até o group by e substitua por
        GROUP BY
            TO_CHAR(trunc(m.date - NUMTODSINTERVAL(15, 'MINUTE')), 'dd/MM/YYYY')
    ) vrdm

Comment: @LeandroLuque agradeço a tentativa, mas não resolveu ainda.

Comment: Consegue compartilhar os Scripts do banco para analisar outros caminhos?

Comment: Basicamente, eu tenho uma tabela que registra dados a cada 15 minutos, valor e hora, e preciso agrupar a soma desses valores por dia, só que o dia não começa 00:00 e termina 23:59, e sim 00:15 e 00:00 (do dia seguinte). Só preciso pensar numa forma que o select trate o horário da 00:00 pertecendo ao dia anterior.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui com a minha sugestão e, pelo que entendi do seu problema, funcionou.
Criei um banco com apenas duas colunas (id, data). Cadastrei as seguintes datas:
(1, 12-JUN-20 12.00.00.000000 AM), (3, 13-JUN-20 12.00.15.000000 AM), (2, 12-JUN-20 11.59.00.000000 PM), (4, 14-JUN-20 12.00.00.000000 AM).

Executei a seguinte pesquisa e ele agrupou corretamente:

SELECT TO_CHAR(data-NUMTODSINTERVAL(15, 'MINUTE'), 'dd/MM/YYYY'), COUNT(*) FROM TESTE458093 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(data-NUMTODSINTERVAL(15, 'MINUTE'), 'dd/MM/YYYY');

Comment: @LeandroLuque dá uma olhada na edição que fiz na pergunta, veja se ficou claro o que preciso.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode calcular a data utilizando `CASE` para verificar se a data esta entre o período de 00:15 ~ 00:00.

Fazendo algo nesse sentido:

```
CASE 
  WHEN DT - TRUNC(DT) >= (1/24/60 * 15) THEN 
    TRUNC(DT) + (1/24/60 * 15) 
   ELSE 
     TRUNC(DT -1) + (1/24/60 * 15) 
END DT_NEW
```

Ficando então:

Se os minutos forem maiores do que 15 minutos, logo a data para agrupamento será no mesmo dia, se não será do dia passado.

Exemplo:

```
WITH dados as (
SELECT 10 vl, to_date('01/01/2010 00:15:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL  
SELECT 20 vl, to_date('02/01/2010 00:14:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 30 vl, to_date('02/01/2010 00:15:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL  
SELECT 40 vl, to_date('03/01/2010 00:14:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual 
),

AJUSTADO AS (
SELECT VL, 
       DT , 
       CASE 
          WHEN DT - TRUNC(DT) >= (1/24/60 * 15) THEN 
            TRUNC(DT) + (1/24/60 * 15) 
           ELSE 
             TRUNC(DT -1) + (1/24/60 * 15) 
       END DT_NEW
 FROM dados 
)

SELECT sum(vl) valor, dt_new 
 FROM AJUSTADO
 GROUP BY dt_new 
 ORder BY dt_new
```

Veja rodando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab5e1d/19).

Comment: Obrigado Bruno pela resposta, eu editei minha pergunta, não sei se a sua solução resolve o que eu preciso, você poderia dar uma olhada no restante da pergunta pra ver se me atende a sua solução.

Comment: Sim atende, é só aplicar o mesmo conceito na sua consulta. Mas isso não vou fazer por você hahaha.